# Can't center two items that are overlaid

Tags: javascript, html, css

I Can't center two items that are overlaid. i want to be on the center of another div and one overlaying on top of another.
The problem is that they are overlaid, but they stay side by side!

```css
#playerOfTeam{
  border: 2px black solid;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: red;
  
}

#banner{
  z-index: 0;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: blue;
}

#rankZone{
  z-index: 11;
  width: 100%;
  /*left: 50%;*/
  /*margin-left: -20px;*/
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="playerOfTeam" >
     <div id="banner">
     </div>
    <div id="rankZone">
    </div>
  </div>
```

How can i overlay the two divs and ploace them in the middle of the first div?

Comment: Why do you think they are overlaying each other -  did you have other code previously to do that? At  the moment they are using the defautl layout which is side-by-side. You should look at using `position:absolute` to overlay them.

Answer (score 1):

Make the parent container `position:relative` (to enable `position:absolute` to work)

Make the underlying containers `position:absolute`

Use `z-index` to stack the two divs atop one another.

Note that `position:absolute` takes the divs out of the normal HTML flow, so things like `width:100%` cannot be used in the same way.

```css
#playerOfTeam{
  position:relative;
  border: 2px black solid;
  height: 400px;
  width: 400px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: red;
  
}

#banner{
  z-index: 1;
  position:absolute;
  top:25%;
  left:0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.5); /* Using 0.5 opacity to bleed colors */
}

#rankZone{
  z-index: 2;
  position:absolute;
  top:25%;
  left:0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.3); /* Using 0.5 opacity to bleed colors */
}

#rankZone{
display:grid;
place-items:center;
color:white;
}
```

```html
<div id="playerOfTeam" >
    <div id="banner"></div>
    <div id="rankZone">Puce/Purplish color a result of green/blue overlaid</div>
</div>
```